How do you drag and drop in SwiftUI?
I currently get the following error:

Instance method 'loadObject(ofClass:completionHandler:)' requires that 'NSItemProvider' conform to '_ObjectiveCBridgeable'

with this code:
.onDrop(of: ["public.text"], isTargeted: nil) { providers, location in
     guard let provider = providers.first else { return false }
             
     provider.loadObject(ofClass: NSItemProvider.self) { item, error in
          guard error == nil, let item = item else { return }
                  
          if let curTool = item as? Tools, let dropURL = item as? URL {
                handleDrop(with: (curTool, dropURL))
          }
     }
     return true
}


func handleDrop(with dropData: (Tools, URL)) {
     let (curTool, curURL) = dropData
}

Here is the matching onDrag (curTool is a simple enum) :
.onDrag {
    let curTool = Tools.circle
    let curURL = URL(string: "https://example.com")!
                    
    let itemProvider = NSItemProvider(object: NSString(string: "Dummy data"))
    itemProvider.registerObject(String(describing: curTool) as NSItemProviderWriting, visibility: .all)
    itemProvider.registerObject(curURL as NSItemProviderWriting, visibility: .all)
    return itemProvider
}

Edit 1 - The suggested method below is not working so I'm trying this method.  Which seams, in the long run, an easier method to understand:
struct DragInfo: Codable {
    let tool: Tools
    let url: URL

    init(_ tool: Tools,_ url: URL ) {
        self.tool   = tool
        self.url        = url
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        tool = try container.decode(Tools.self, forKey: .tool)
        url = try container.decode(URL.self, forKey: .url)
    }
}


.onDrag {
    let draggedData = DragInfo( .furniture, URL(string: "file://abc.txt") ?? URL(fileURLWithPath: ""))
    let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(draggedData)
    print( "onDrag: \(draggedData)" )
    return NSItemProvider(item: data as NSSecureCoding?, typeIdentifier: "xxx")
}

Unfortunately this results the following core foundation crash:
There are 0 items on the pasteboard, but 1 drag images. There must be 1 draggingItem per pasteboardItem.  

It occurs right after the print statement prints to the console but before I release the mouse.

You are using the loadObject method wrong - as the ofClass parameter, you need to pass the type you want to load with the NSItemProvider, not NSItemProvider itself:
provider.loadObject(ofClass: Tools.self) { item, error in
    guard error == nil, let item = item else { return }
              
    [...]
}

However, above also means you must conform your Tools type to NSItemProviderReading. Which as I see you haven't done, instead you transformed it into a String, so in your current code form it would be:
provider.loadObject(ofClass: String.self) { item, error in
    guard error == nil, let item = item else { return }
           
    [convert `item` (a String) back to the Tools custom type you have...]
}

Rather than using the String(describing:) method, I would suggest adding a String raw value to your enum:
enum Tools: String {
   case circle
   ...
}

which automatically adds two members: init?(rawValue: String) and var rawValue: String to your Tools enum, as described here for conversion from and to String.
Also, you cannot load both your representations in a single loadObject() call, you need to make another one for the URL and handle the result similarly:
.onDrop(of: ["public.text"], isTargeted: nil) { providers, location in
     guard let provider = providers.first else { return false }
             
     provider.loadObject(ofClass: String.self) { rawItem, error in
        guard error == nil, rawItem != nil, item = Tools(rawValue: rawItem!) else { return }
                  
        [...]
     }

     provider.loadObject(ofClass: URL.self) { item, error in
         guard error == nil, let item = item else { return }
                  
         [...]
     }

     return true
}


Extra note
If your operating system support allows, do take a look at the new Transferable protocol and its drag-and-drop support via draggable() and dropDestination().

I'm on MacOS using latest OS.  I find onDrop and onDrag a bit hard to use.  I'd rather something that looks like a standard function would make it MUCH easier to deal with :).  I'll take a look at the the two functions above hope it is easier to deal with.

OK, I took a look at the Draggable() and dropDestination() APIs and they do look quit a bit more understandable / standard.  I'm not feeling that well right now so I'll get back to you in a couple of days once I've had a chance to experiment with it.  Have to integrate it into a list control I've created.  Oh I get an out of scope for draggable so I'll be back later

Sorry, @iSpain17 I just returned.  I tried to get this to work and couldn't.  Yes I removed the ... statements :).   My tools are just a simple enum but there are some 60 tools.  Converting the string back into the enum is not maintainable.  I also tried the drawable API but also couldn't get that running.  It's all seams to be conversion issues where my simple enum cannot be passed over from drag to the drop.  All I have is a simple enum and the URL and the URL seams to cause less issues.  curTool and curURL is all I want to pass.

You have many tools to fight that - you can either conform your Tools enum to NSItemProviderWriting and NSItemProviderReading, however conversion from and to String isn't really hard if you make your Tools enum have a String raw value: enum Tools: String { ... } because then you convert to String with Tools.someCase.rawValue and convert from String with Tools.init(rawValue: someString) - updated my answer with these details.

That sounds good... do I need to add an init method for Tools to get this to work?

Ahh that seams to be closer but I get this error:  Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'.  I want to be sure we update this with the correct info so it compiles for everybody.

Ye, i forgot item is optional!

Unfortunately I couldn't get your suggestion to work so I'm trying another method.  Which I documented above in Edit-1 in my original posting.  I think it is easier to understand but it has a totally different issue.
